# File or assembly name 'System, Version=3.9.0.0, Culture=neutra', or one of its dependencies, was not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, frameworks, windows-embedded-8

I developed a software in *Windows Embedded 2013* using *Visual Studio 2015* and the *.Net 3.9 Compact* framework. But when I try to deploy the software, it says:

> "File or assembly name 'System, Version=3.9.0.0, Culture=neutra', or one of its dependencies, was not found."

I understand that the problem theoretically is that the framework 3.9 is not installed. But it is, and I already tried to set the `system.dll` to copy to the deployed system.

This is the code that I'm trying to run:

If instead of

```
Application.Run(new frmprincipal());
```

I change it to:

```
Console.writeline("abcdefg")
```

it works perfectly.
But I really need some help on this.

```
using System.Windows.Forms
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Run(new frmprincipal());
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do?